# Testlink and bugzilla integration bugAdd.php blank page

Tags: bugzilla, testlink

I am new to Testlink . I have some issues with integrating testlink and bugzilla. For some reason
1) when I click the create issue button it just loads a blank page with the url: /testlink/lib/execute/bugAdd.php?user_action=create&tcversion_id=4&tproj ect_id=1&exec_id=8

When I try to load just the bugAdd.php page without any parameters it loads a "Add Bug Report" page that just has a close button.

I am using Testlink 1.9.8 with Bugzilla 4.4

```
xmlrpc config:

<!-- Template bugzillaxmlrpcInterface -->
<issuetracker>
<username><bugzilla admin></username>
<password><bugzilla admin pw></password>
<uribase>http://<bugzilla ip address>/</uribase>
<product>Test</product>
<component>Test1</component>
</issuetracker>
```

The product and component tags in the config I actually used my bugzilla product called "Test" and component called "Test1", is this right?

2)when i click "link existence issue" icon the Add bug window opens if i enter the bug id and click "Add bug" button then a blank page gets displayed.
Can anyone say where am i going wrong. I tried searching but no luck..why Testlink forums are not that active..

Log Warning :
E_NOTICE Undefined property: stdClass::$msg - in /var/www/testlink/gui/templates_c/e7ab14687ea39f270d824245a5ca4e926130d6c6.file.bugAdd.tpl.php - Line 43

Thanks in advance,
sarah.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had identical problem while trying to integrate TL with Redmine.
Try to install the **php-mbstring.x86_64** library on the server with TL - it helped me...
Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten quite a bit of information in your TestLink interface settings..change them to match what you have setup in Bugzilla.

//your settings as you describe...

```
<username><bugzilla admin></username>
<password><bugzilla admin pw></password>
<uribase>http://<bugzilla ip address>/</uribase>
<product>Test</product>
<component>Test1</component>
```

//missing settings

```
<version>unspecified</version>
<severity>Trivial</severity>
<op_sys>All</op_sys>
<priority>Normal</priority>
<platform>All</platform>
```

just make sure to enclose it all in the issuetracker tags

anyway, hope that helps...